# Entity Framework Where(Func<Car, bool>) clause not going to server

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to pass a "Where" clause to a method via a method parameter but I have found that the where clause is not getting sent to the database server. The query actual fetches all of the records and then the "Where" is applied by EF in the client application.

Here is an example to demonstrate my problem:

```
// ID  Name         Colour
// -----------------------
// 3   RED_CAR      RED
// 4   WHITE_CAR    WHITE
// 5   BLUE_CAR     BLUE

using (QDBEntities db = new QDBEntities())
{
    // #1 - no variable "Where" - where sent to server, result is correct.
    foreach (var car in db.Cars.Where(r => r.Colour == "RED"))
        Console.WriteLine(car.ID + " " + car.Name);
    // Output:      3 RED_CAR
    // Profiler:   ... FROM [dbo].[Car] AS [Extent1]
    // WHERE N'RED' = [Extent1].[Colour]

    // #2 - using a variable "Where" - where NOT sent to server, result is correct.
    Func<Car, bool> where = new Func<Car, bool>(r => r.Colour == "RED");
    foreach (var car in db.Cars.Where(where))
        Console.WriteLine(car.ID + " " + car.Name);
    // Output:      3 RED_CAR
    // Profiler:    FROM [dbo].[Car] AS [Extent1] ** NO WHERE CLAUSE **
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass an [**expression tree**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) to `Where()` so that EF can see what it does an convert it to SQL.

Change `Func<Car, bool>` to `Expression<Func<Car, bool>>`.

Comment: Spot on - thank you. I spent way too long on my own looking for an answer to this.